# How can I utilize the Add-WindowsCapability function through a proxy in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, proxy, openssh, windows-server-2019

I am trying to install OpenSSH on a Windows Server 2019 machine in an environment without external network access and with a configured proxy at "[http://10.99.99.99:80](http://10.99.99.99/)". I am using PowerShell with administrative privileges and have set the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables as follows:

```
$Proxy = "http://10.99.99.99:80"
$ENV:HTTP_PROXY=$proxy
$ENV:HTTPS_PROXY=$proxy
```

However, when I try to install OpenSSH using the following command:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

I receive the following error:

```
Add-WindowsCapability : Add-WindowsCapability failed. Error code = 0x800f0954 At line:1 char:1 + Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-WindowsCapability], COMException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.AddWindowsCapabilityCommand
```

Other Invoke-WebRequests I am making seem to have proxy access, but the Add-WindowsCapability command is not working. I am unable to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message has error code `0x800f0954`, you may want try doing the following steps:

- Open `gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System
- Double click on `Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair` to open its settings
- Check "Enabled" in the popup dialog
- Check `Download repair content and optional features directly from Windows Updates instead of Windows Server Updates Services (WSUS)`
- Open Powershell, Run `gpupdate /force`
- Rerun the `Add-WindowsCapability` again, it should be fixed

Comment: Oh, I see. I was thinking in the wrong direction. I thought it was a problem with the PROXY.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my solution. I searched a lot to solve this issue, because I wanted to solve this without changing the Group Policy's and wanted to use the CAB file as Source.

I used the following command:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0 -Source {path to the cab file} -LimitAccess
```

Every time I got an error. But then I looked at the logfile:
`C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\cbs.log` and realized that I used the wrong version of the CAB file. In the log file you can also see the expected version.
After downloading the right version, everything worked as expected!